# How to parse for wildcard values in dictionary inside a list?

Tags: python

How do you parse dictionaries using wildcard values inside a list? I have a large list with numerous dicts and want to pull out data for all dicts and dump into a new dict, using keys that match a wildcard value.

For example, I'd like to retrieve data for all keys that match the value "Tom*" and dump into a new dict list2:

```
list = [
       {"name": "Tom David Smith", "age": 10, "sex": "M"},
       {"name": "Tom Harrison", "age": 5, "sex": "M"},
       {"name": "Pam", "age": 7, "sex": "F"}
       ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension and check the names with `str.startwith()` method :

```
>>> [d for d in l if d['name'].startswith('Tom')]
[{'age': 10, 'name': 'Tom David Smith', 'sex': 'M'}, {'age': 5, 'name': 'Tom Harrison', 'sex': 'M'}]
```

Comment: Thank you Kasra, worked perfectly! How do I rate you to give you credit for the response? I'm new to stacked overflow.